# debugging dump file to find cause of memory usage spike

Tags: c#, debugging, dump

A service deployed to the Service Fabric started spiking in CPU and Memory usage. I was given a dump file to analyze, and am not sure what to do with it. I opened the dump file in VSTS 2019 and have attempted *Debugging with Managed only*, and *Debugging Managed Memory*. 
[image]
*Debugging with Managed only* hasn't given me any information (the breakpoints say that symbols have not been loaded), and *Debugging Managed Memory* brings me to this image: [image] where it's obvious there's a giant issue but doesn't tell me how it happened.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: There are six huge List<double> totaling 2 GB. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to find out what those List<double>s look like? Or what function call led to them?

Comment: Do you have the PDBs?

Comment: I'm sure I can generate them.